# Trying to get property 'symbol' of non-object

Tags: php

help solve the problem. "Trying to get property 'symbol' of non-object"

**It is the line:**

```
return $currency->symbol;
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Currency;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class CurrencyConversion
{
    public const DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE = 'RUB';

    protected static $container;

    public static function loadContainer()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$container)) {
            $currencies = Currency::get();
            foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
                self::$container[$currency->code] = $currency;
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getCurrencies()
    {
        self::loadContainer();

        return self::$container;
    }

    public static function getCurrencyFromSession()
    {
        return session('currency', self::DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE);
    }

    public static function getCurrentCurrencyFromSession()
    {
        self::loadContainer();
        $currencyCode = self::getCurrencyFromSession();

        foreach (self::$container as $currency) {
            if ($currency->code === $currencyCode) {
                return $currency;
            }
        }
    }

    public static function convert($sum, $originCurrencyCode = self::DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, $targetCurrencyCode = null)
    {
        self::loadContainer();

        $originCurrency = self::$container[$originCurrencyCode];

        if ($originCurrency->code != self::DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE) {
            if ($originCurrency->rate != 0 || $originCurrency->updated_at->startOfDay() != Carbon::now()->startOfDay()) {
                CurrencyRates::getRates();
                self::loadContainer();
                $originCurrency = self::$container[$originCurrencyCode];
            }
        }

        if (is_null($targetCurrencyCode)) {
            $targetCurrencyCode = self::getCurrencyFromSession();
        }

        $targetCurrency = self::$container[$targetCurrencyCode];
        if ($originCurrency->code != self::DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE) {
            if ($targetCurrency->rate == 0 || $targetCurrency->updated_at->startOfDay() != Carbon::now()->startOfDay()) {
                CurrencyRates::getRates();
                self::loadContainer();
                $targetCurrency = self::$container[$targetCurrencyCode];
            }
        }

        return $sum / $originCurrency->rate * $targetCurrency->rate;
    }

    public static function getCurrencySymbol()
    {
        self::loadContainer();

        $currencyFromSession = self::getCurrencyFromSession();

        $currency = self::$container[$currencyFromSession];
        return $currency->symbol;
    }

    public static function getBaseCurrency()
    {
        self::loadContainer();

        foreach (self::$container as $code => $currency) {
            if ($currency->isMain()) {
                return $currency;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCurrenciesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('symbol');
            $table->tinyInteger('is_main')->default(0);
            $table->double('rate')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('currencies');
    }
}
```

The production database contains invalid values in the table, but I'm not really sure about that

I apologize in advance for a possibly stupid question, but I'm just learning and trying to figure it out, but so far everything is even

Comment: Are you sure $currency is an object not an array? Have you do a dump of the $currency to see what it is?

Comment: You seem to be bending over backwards to accommodate a lot of state in a static class. You could probably simplify your code quite a bit by using non-static class instances instead.